# Naming axis of Matlab figures depending on indices: error when using $\Phi$

Tags: matlab

I'm having some issues with changing the axis names of some Matlab figures depending on some pre-defined indices.

Consider the following code:

```
clear
rng default
Phi{1,1}=randn(3,1);
Phi{1,2}=randn(3,1);
Phi{2,1}=randn(3,1);
Phi{2,2}=randn(3,1);
```

Suppose I want to plot `Phi{i,k}` versus `Phi{j,h}` across various `i,k,j,h` and then name the axis **$\Phi_{ik}$ and $\Phi_{jh}$**, respectively (in Latex language).

I have tried the following

```
    i=1; 
    k=2;
    j=2;
    h=1;
    figure
    scatter(Phi{i,k}, Phi{j,h}, 100,'k', 'filled')
    xlabel(sprintf('\Phi_{%i%k}',i,k),'FontSize', 25) 
    ylabel(sprintf('\Phi_{%j%h}',j,h),'FontSize', 25)
```

I get the error: `Warning: Escaped character '\P' is not valid.` Could you advise on how I can fix this?

---

If I don't use `sprintf` everything works fine:

```
figure
scatter(Phi{i,k}, Phi{j,h}, 100,'k', 'filled')
xlabel('\Phi_{12}','FontSize', 25) 
ylabel('\Phi_{21}','FontSize', 25)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use [`sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html#btf_bfy-1_sep_shared-formatSpec), you must protect literal `\` characters to stop `sprintf` thinking you're trying to use a "special character" (as listed in that doc page). Basically, in the format specifier to `sprintf` (i.e. the first argument), literal `\` characters need to be doubled, like so:

```
i = 7; k = 3;
xlabel(sprintf('\\Phi_{%d%d}', i, k))
```

Comment: Thanks: I'm still having troubles with the double index:     `xlabel(sprintf('\\Phi_{%i%k}',i,k),'FontSize', 25) ` gives error `String scalar or character vector must have valid interpreter syntax:
\Phi_`

Comment: `%k` is not a valid format specifier, use `%i` or `%d` for both. I'll update my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be to just concatenate strings:

```
 xlabel(['\Phi_{',num2str(i),num2str(k),'}'])
```